# How can I make instances real and keep their orientation?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

[image]

How can I make these instances real and keep their current orientation? When I use the command Make Instances Real, it creates real instances that then have the same geometry nodes setup, creating this:
[image]

I can then delete the Geometry Nodes modifier on each of the real instances, but their orientation then changes and they are all facing upward. I want their orientations to remain how they are in the first screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Transform Geometry node and use Rotate Instances to rotate Y axis 90 degrees, you still gonna need to manually remove all the geo nodes modifier after Make Instances Real command.

Or you can add Realize Instances node at the end, and just apply geo nodes modifier, note that all instances becomes single mesh.